# Make a form to click on colors and send value in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

I am having a form with 3 choices for example for colors like below :

```
 <form action="{{ route('shop.products.index', $product->url_key) }}" method="get">
  <select name="color_id">
    <option value="1">black</option>
    <option value="2">brown</option>
    <option value="3">white</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

now instead of having a select with options I want to place 3 circles of black brown and white color and when user clicks on each of them form will be submited with that value . any how to do that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the circles use the `<label>` element for each input. This label can be styled so it will show a circle as an option. The input itself can be hidden with `display: none` to only show the label. If the input is inside the label it will trigger a change in the input when clicked.

With JavaScript, listen for the `change` event inside the form. A change event occurs whenever the value (or selection) of an input has been changed. Then trigger the form submit manually with the `.submit()` method.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  form.submit();
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.circle {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  margin: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle input {
  display: none;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.brown {
  background-color: brown;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label class="circle black">
    <input type="radio" name="color_id" value="black">
  </label>
  <label class="circle brown">
    <input type="radio" name="color_id" value="brown">
  </label>
  <label class="circle white">
    <input type="radio" name="color_id" value="white">
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly what think is that you can do it with css.
make sure to use the  tag.
in it use rounded-border
and then increase the radius of it.

or else you can use image tag with css again.

Comment: sorry i think i asked question a bit bad i meant how to submit form when clicking on those circles

Comment: oh, no worries, then you can css on the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you can try something like this. The selectColor functon will set the select field value and it will remain hidden from view. The divs represent your circles which you can click to set select field.

```
<form id="theForm">
  <div>
     <div class="black" onclick="selectColor(1)"></div>
     <div class="brown" onclick="selectColor(2)"></div>
     <div class="white" onclick="selectColor(3)"></div>
  </div>
  <select  name="color_id" style="visiblity:hidden" id="color_id">
      <option value="1">black</option>
      <option value="2">brown</option>
      <option value="3">white</option>
  </select>
</form>
<script>

  selectColor(color){
    document.getElementById('theForm').submit(); // Submit form
    document.getElementById('color_id').value = color;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: what if i dont want to click on a send button i mean when user clicks on the color it submits form automatically

Comment: you can acces the value in the script so you are half way done. document.getElementById('theForm').submit();

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<select>` for `<input type="radio">`.

So you will have something like:

```html
<input type="radio" name="color_id" value="1" /> <img src="some_black_circle.jpg" />
<input type="radio" name="color_id" value="2" /> <div class="css_brown_circle"></div>
<input type="radio" name="color_id" value="3" /> <img src="some_white_circle.jpg" />
<input type="submit" value="send">
```

Comment: what if i dont want to click on a send button i mean when user clicks on the color it submits form automatically

Comment: You'll need javascript in `onclick` input attribute, similar to @Mr Khan answer.